# Ghost change my data after close form

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a little databes in access. I make a few forms with sub forms and drop list(by query):

[image]

Steps of my creating form:

1. make form from table
2. delete all not PK or FK text box
3. create comboBox with store value to text box what I choase
4. create subForm    and set Link Master Fields and child fields

design view:

[image]

This is form for table Task task have Fk: Project, peson etc. DropLists are connected tu subform for changing FK like project, person etc. So when I work i select in droplists what i want add to database and work with subForm. When I close this form, **the first row in table change FK to last configuration on droplists**.. Pleas how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have any code behind your form? If so, you should add a breakpoint. It may be difficult to decide where, however. Do you have a close button? How do you close your form? Do you have a Current event? Do you have any code that updates the subform?

Comment: NO i do not have any code behind.. , and i do not have any button.. only close form by X on right or right click on heda and chose close.. It is small databes with MS access forms.. realy realy small..

Comment: How are the drop lists connected to the subform?

Comment: During winzard of combobox i Store that value in field on form ... and Subform have Link Master Fields and Ciheld Fields on form id_projekt;id_os_udaje etc. this is text field what is invisible on form but droplist stor to that values..

Comment: Steps of my creating form:
1 make form from table
2 delete all not PK or FK text box
3 create comboBox with store value to text box what i choase
4 create subForm and set Link Master Fields and child fields

Comment: Is the projekt_id you are selecting in the combo from the same table as the invisible textbox? What is the subform table?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13342/discussion-between-remou-and-eddy-screamer)

Comment: ok :) btw: sub form is from the same table like form.. and combo box is from query or other table ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite possible to use a main form for selecting and updating subform records, but in this case it should not be a bound form.

To set up, for want of a better word, a linking form, unbind the main form, that is remove the record source and ensure the dropdowns (comboboxes) do not have control sources. I suggest you rename the dropdowns to cbo, to indicate that they are controls, not fields. The hidden controls should not be needed.

The value of a combobox is the value of the bound column. The Key or FK is the first item in your SELECT statement and the bound column is 1 (one) so the relevant Key or FK is the value of each comboboxe. You can set the link master fields to the names of controls so the Link Master Fields should be `cbo_id_projekt;cbo_id_os_udaje;cbo_id_komponent;cbo_id_uloha`.

As an aside, I generally avoid underscores, but each to their own.